# map inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, dictionary

I have a parent class which holds a map and n the child class i  have used to inherit that class with for some reason can't access the map which i can't under stand why, i want to access the values inside the map.

my code is as follows

```
//HEADER FILE 
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

//////PARENT CLASS
struct TTYElementBase
{
    //some code here
};

class element
{
    public:

        std::map<char,std::string> transMask;
        std::map<char,std::string>::iterator it;

        void populate();
};

//////CHILD CLASS .HPP

class elementV : public element
{
public :
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2;
    elementV();
    friend ostream &operator<< (ostream &, const elementV &);
    void transLateMask();
};

//CPP FILE 
#include "example.h"
#include <iostream>

elementV::elementV()
{
}

void elementV::transLateMask()
{
    for ( it=transMask.begin() ; it != transMask.end(); it++ )
        cout << (*it).first << endl;
}

int main()
{
    elementV v;
    v.transLateMask();
}

// ' OUTPUT IS NOTHING I DONT KNOW WHY?'
```

output is nothing but i need to acces the map fron the parent class, what am i doing wrong?

any help i will be very gratefull

Thanks

Comment: The program compiles but fails at runtime?

Comment: Do the map have an entry indexed by `'D'`?

Comment: Can you show how the map is populated? If `D` is not present then you are deferencing a past-the-end iterator, which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @hmjd the map is populated like this `transMask['D']="[0-9]"`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes there is an entry indexed by `'D'` the map looks like this `transMask['D']="[0-9]"`

Comment: @ShamariCampbell: In that case, perhaps you could post a small, complete program that exhibits the problem? Otherwise, all we can do is guess.

Comment: Also, it would help if you told us exactly what error you get.

Comment: @MikeSeymour i have a program at the top which shows everything

Comment: @ShamariCampbell: That program never puts anything in `transMask`. Why are you surprised that it's empty? I'm sure that if you put something in it (e.g. using the code in your other comments), then it will appear when you print the contents, and `find()` will succeed.

Comment: See [here](http://ideone.com/E04Ur) for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the map contain an entry for `'D'` when you call `transLateMask()`? You'll get undefined behaviour (perhaps a runtime error) if it doesn't, since you don't check the result of `find()`. Something like this would be more robust:

```
auto found = transMask.find('D');
if (found == transMask.end()) {
    // handle the error in some way, perhaps
    throw std::runtime_error("No D in transMask");
}

std::string str = found->second;
```

(If you're not using C++11, then replace `auto` with the full type name, `std::map<char,std::string>::const_iterator`).

Alternatively, C++11 adds an `at()` method which throws `std::out_of_range` if the key is not found:

```
std::string str = transMask.at('D')->second;
```

Comment: yes there is a D in the map the map looks like this `transMask['D']="[0-9]"`

Comment: And it's definitely populated *before* calling `transLateMask`? In that case, there's some problem in the code you haven't shown us; could you post a short, complete program to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The `find()` method of the `std::map` can return an iterator that is "one beyond the end" of the map, i.e. equals to result of `end()`. This means there's no such entry in the map. You have to check for that:

```
typedef std::map<char,std::string> mymap;
mymap::const_iterator i = transMask.find('D');

if ( i == transMask.end()) {
    std::cerr << "'D' not found" << std::endl;
} else {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Yes there is a D in the map the map is populated like this `transMap['D']="[0-9]` surely that should be fine right @Nikolai N Fetissov